# Why $\lambda$ is a complex number in the topic of "Stablity in numerical methods"?

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I am studying the stability of numerical methods. In this topic we take a numerical methods such as Forward Euler and we try to find the condition that make it stable or unstable.

for Forward Euler we have:

$ x_{n+1} = x_n + h f(t,x) , \qquad x' = f(x,t) = \lambda x(t) $

$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \lambda h x_n $

$ x_{n+1} = (1+\lambda h) x_n $

By induction: $x_n = (1+ \lambda h)^n x_0$

We can see that in order for the above iteration to converge when $n \rightarrow \infty$, we must have: $|(1+\lambda h)| < 1$

Now here the author of the article which I am reading sets $\lambda h = z$ and then assumes for a complex $\lambda$

$D_{Euler} = \{ z = \lambda h \in C: |z+1| < 1\}$

Which is a circle with radius 1, centered at origin of the complex plane.

My question is why do we need to consider complex numbers? It seems to me that the value of $\lambda$ can be only real. Why we need to consider $\lambda$ as a complex number?

Comment: I can think of two answers at the moment. One is that studying $y'=\lambda y$ for complex $\lambda$ allows you to study growth, decay, and oscillation, which can occur together even in first order ODEs in real variables (though they will need to be non-autonomous). A method which behaves OK for exponential decay but poorly for exponential decay with some oscillation is not so great. Another is that these methods can be extended to higher order equations or systems; these systems can look exactly like $y'=\lambda y$ for complex $y$ (for example, $y''+2Re(\lambda)y'+|\lambda|^2y=0$).

Comment: Ian: I see. So to wrap up your comment: it is basically there to let the expansion of the concept possible, in more advanced cases.

Comment: Basically, and to do so in a rather convenient fashion for analysis.